# Deletar registro da tabela com chave estrangeira

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Onde está o Erro?

```
DELETE FROM postagens WHERE id='$p_id' AND u_id='$u_id' SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Esclarecimentos:

p_id = id das postagens(chave primária)

u_id = id do usuário(chave estrangeira)

Comment: Qual foi a mensagem de erro reportada pelo PHP e/ou MySQL?

Comment: Nenhum erro, no entanto está retornando -1 linhas afetadas! $comm = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; DELETE * FROM postagens WHERE id='$p_id' AND u_id='$u_id'; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;";

Comment: Coloque isso dentro de um try catch e edite sua resposta colocando a mensagem de erro que ocorre

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que você deve primeiro executar o `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` e em seguida o `DELETE FROM ...;`. Ambos com seu respectivo `;` visto que são comandos distintos.